# When articles are not used

Tags: grammar, articles

Why don't the below sentences have articles:

> 1. He is of Asian origin.
> 2. They belonged to Africa.

What are they not:

> 1. He is of **an** Asian origin.
> 2. They belonged to **the** Africa.

I came across another similar sentence, which has article in it:

> She is **a** European.

Comment: _A European_ is _a person from Europe_. We don't use an article with names of countries or continents, so we would never refer to _the Africa_. _Asian_ is an  adjective describing _origin_, and the phrase doesn't need an article.

Comment: There is no reason. There is no reason for us to use any articles, at all, ever. Your best bet is to learn it all by heart. Just like every single native speaker has to. That is the only way. There are no shortcuts. There can't be. Because articles have no reason to exist in the first place.

Comment: Unless of course the geographical location takes an article, in which case you might say eg “They belong to The Hague”, or even “They come from the Ukraine”. But Africa, etc, do not take an article in the above cases.

Comment: I think that the sense of those statements makes an article inappropriate, regardless of whether the geographical word is replaced. For example I would say "he is of humble origins," not "of a humble origin," because nobody should respond to my words by asking "which humble origin?" That's not the meaning, that he's of any particular humble origin, but just that his origin is humble.

Comment: (1) ' ...are of adj (eg Asian /  African /  ancient / recent) origin' are set phrases. //// (2) Arguably, there **is** an (invisible) article in 'They belonged to Africa', the null article (not the zero article ... 'We are having chicken tonight'). Even more prestigious than the definite article. 'She is the boss!' '_He is King_!' // Compare/contrast 'They belonged to Africa ... an Africa vastly different from the Africa of today.'

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth I'm not sure I understand the scope of this analysis. Would expressions like He is of slight build, quiet demeanor, little importance, pleasant appearance, etc., all be explained as "set phrases"? Is that then the answer to the original question? I'm not sure I understand what the question was really asking, if this is the answer.

Comment: @Chaim It's where I'd go. Take 'of little importance', for instance. There theoretically exist similar prepositional-phrase qualifiers ('of tiny importance', 'of fair importance' (note that 'fairly important' exists) but some are little used. 'Of high importance' can replace 'highly important' whereas 'of high irregularity' can't replace 'highly irregular', and neither can 'of Africa' replace 'African' in 'He is African'. This shows behaviour suggestive of idioms. // The of-phrases used predicatively (right after the copula)  rarely take a definite article. These are all of + Adj + Nabstract.

Comment: Not using an article is known as "going commando".

Comment: He is of an Asian origin. Father from Singapore. Mother from Hong Kong.

Answer (score 1):

This is an effort to summarize the comments thus far, with a bit of my own editorializing.

1. Some of your examples can be explained by the relationship of articles to proper-noun geographic terms. We would never say something like “I traveled to the Africa” or “I am from the England,” because *Africa* and *England* are the names of places, and the names of places do not take articles except in a certain few examples, in which cases the articles are part of the name and cannot be omitted. In this latter category I’ve thought of the Bahamas, the Democratic Republic of Congo, the Dominican Republic, the Hague, the Ivory Coast, the Maldives, the Marshall Islands, the Netherlands, the People’s Republic of China, the Philippines, the Republic of Congo, the Solomon Islands, the Ukraine, the United Arab Emirates, the United Kingdom, the United States (of America), and the Virgin Islands (which are sometimes distinguished as the American or British Virgin Islands). Thus, they belong to Africa, not to “the” Africa. (Of course with common-noun geographical terms we use articles normally: a, an or the + continent, desert, forest, island, mainland, river, etc.)
2. But many proper-noun place-names have related adjectives, and putting articles in front of these words can make them nouns after all. For example writing “27 November” instead of “November 27” is European, but Angela Merkel is a European = somebody from Europe. Merkel is also European, and we would have to [rack](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/rack-vs-wrack) our brains to think of a setting in which this distinction is important.
3. There are many phrases on the “of Asian origins” model that follow the same “Of” + Adjective + Noun pattern without any article: He is of slight build, quiet demeanor, little importance, pleasant appearance, etc., all without an article. That usage is a “set phrase,” apparently meaning that we just do it that way. It seems to me that in these examples there is a vagueness about the statement that would make it inappropriate to ask, for example, “Which Asian origin is he of,” (or “Which slight build” etc.) The answer to those questions would be the silly, obvious fact: “Well he is of his Asian origins.” On the other hand we would use the article in this very same grammatical pattern where the question would make more sense. I am visiting the capital ***of an Asian country***. Which one? Thailand. I am the founder ***of a successful business***. Which one? Facebook. So it seems to me that the article missing from your example (He is of Asian origins) is an expression of this vagueness.